# Object defined on $scope becoming undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my directive controller I have a $watch like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return service.abc;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  $scope.abc = {abc: newVal};
});
```

I have noticed that I am having problems with this variable becoming undefined when used in other controllers. I set up another watch:

```
 $scope.$watch('abc', function () {
     console.log($scope.abc);
 });
```

With this watch I see that the abc object becomes defined with the value from the service, but then afterwards gets undefined. I am sure that I am not modifying this object anywhere. Even if I set

```
$scope.abc = {abc: angular.copy(newVal)};
```

to ensure the object does not get modified, it still becomes undefined. I have tried using the vm controllerAs syntax and trying different variable names to make sure it was not getting modified, but it still becomes undefined. What's going on? I need to pass this object into a directive, and be able to modify it from this parent controller and have the inner directive controller reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, scope variables wether in controllers or directives need to be initialize every time the controller or directive is started.

It appears you want use the variables set in services, which should be fine because they are singletons and the values will persists from page to page during the life of the application.

The watch is designed to watch scope variables in controllers and directives so when you use:

```
$scope.$watch('abc', function () {
    console.log($scope.abc);
});
```

You are watching the scope variable named abc in the controller/directive.  If you don't initialize abc in your controller/directive, then this watch will never get fired.

Also, make sure you use this syntax to define watches in controllers/directives:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.$watch('abc', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal != oldVal) {
      // do something here
    }
}));
```

This definition prevents the watch from running multiple times if you were to enter the page, exit and re-enter the page.  The watch are defined multiple times, but not destroyed.